# Browser History entry when POST form to to iframe with javascript (IE)

Tags: post, iframe, browser, browser-history

Basically i want to automatically POST content to a form without using XMLHttpRequest.

The site works fine but there is a problem with the browser history when getting back to the page by clicking the browser back button.

My site looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>History Problem</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            try {
                if ("<%= Request.Form["hiddenField1"] == null %>" == "True") {
                    var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
                    var theIframe = document.createElement('iframe');                    
                    theIframe.id = theIframe.name = "myIframe";             
                    document.body.appendChild(theIframe);
                    theForm.hiddenField1.value = "SomeValue";
                    theForm.submit();
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                var x = e;
            }
        };

        window.onunload = function () { };


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="myForm" action="" target="myIframe" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenField1" name="hiddenField1" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.google.com">External Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The trace shows that there is a GET and a POST request. everything is fine so far. But if you click on "External Link" (google.com) and then back to the site, you'll see two  history entries for the test site. Also the google.com history entry seems to be gone.

This happens only in Internet Explorer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out, that IE only requests the POST when navigating back to the page. but not the POST->GET as firefox does. But still no idea why

Comment: ok, i finally resolved that issue by adding these no-cache response headers:

    Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.